# Export data from branch through API

Tags: branch.io

I am using the below mentioned url but unable to fetch data.Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

https://api2.branch.io/v3/export/XXXXX?branch_secret=XXXXX&export_date=2019-03-06

When I run this url with the required keys I get an error message like

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.13.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data export API is a premium solution part of Branch's Data Feeds Product. If you are already subscribed, please reach out to integrations@branch.io for help with this export.

Comment: Thank you for your help.